# Characterization Projection operator as distance minimizer

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $V$ be a subspace of $H$.
How can I prove that for a map $P \colon H \rightarrow V$ the following are equivalent:

1. $P^2=P$ and $P$ is linear
2. $P(x) = \operatorname{argmin}_{y \in V} \langle x-y,x-y \rangle^2.$

Comment: Question is not clear: I suppose condition 1 is $P^2=P$ and linearity, but what is condtion 2? "Exists $V$ subspace of $H$ such that for all $x\in$..."

Comment: I rewrote it to make it clearer, sorry for the mixup

Comment: What do you mean by $P^2 = 1$? Do you mean $P^2 = P$? Edit: Judging from the revision history you changed the statement of your question. The problem is that in your original question $V$ depends on $P$ (which is needed if you mean $P^2 = P$), while this is not the case in the current version of the question.

Comment: Sorry it should read $P^2=P$, must have been a typo..

Comment: As stated, the result is false. $\operatorname{argmin}_{y\in V}\langle x, y \rangle^2 = 0$ for all $x$. Given the title talks about minimizing distance, not inner product, perhaps you mean $$P(x) = \operatorname{argmin}_{y\in V}\langle y - x, y - x \rangle^2\text{?}$$

Comment: Yes that's what i meant; sorry late night post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even with the correction I gave in the comment, this just isn't true:

Consider $H = \Bbb R^2, V = \{(r, 0) \mid x \in \Bbb R\}$. Let $P(r,s) = (r - s,0)$. Then $P$ is linear, $P^2 = P$, and $P(H) = V$, but if $x = (2,1)$, $$P(x) = (1,0)$$ while $$\operatorname{argmin}_{y\in V}\langle y - x, y - x \rangle^2 = (2,0)$$ and $$\operatorname{argmin}_{y\in V}\langle y, x \rangle^2 = (0,0)$$

You need stronger conditions on $P$ for this to hold.

**Added:**

In addition to requiring that $\ker P \perp V$ is added to condition (1), it is also necessary to require that $V$ be closed. Otherwise the argmin in (2) will be empty for certain values of $x$ and thus cannot be equal to $P(x)$. The statement should be:

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $V$ a closed subspace of $H$. If $P\ :\ H \to V$, then the following two conditions are equivalent:
>
> 1. $P$ is linear, $P^2 = P$, and $\ker P \perp V$.
> 2. For all $x \in H, P(x) = \operatorname{argmin}_{y \in V} \|y - x\|$.

I will assume that $H$ is a real Hilbert space. The same result is true for complex Hilbert spaces, but some adjustments are needed in the proof.

Proof:

Since squaring is a strictly increasing function on non-negatives, $$\operatorname{argmin}_{y \in V} \|y - x\| = \operatorname{argmin}_{y \in V} \|y - x\|^2.$$
I will switch between using the two forms freely. Note also that $\|y - x\|^2 = \|y\|^2 + \|x\|^2 - 2\langle y, x \rangle$.

(1) $\implies$ (2):

Let $x \in H, v = P(x) \in V$ and $u = x - v$. Now $P(u) = P(x - v) = P(x) - P^2(x) = 0$, so $u \in \ker P$ and thus $u \perp V$. Hence for $y \in V$,
$$\begin{align}\|y - x\|^2 &= \langle y - v - u, y - v - u \rangle\\
&= \|y - v\|^2 + \|u\|^2 - 2\langle y -v, u\rangle\\
&= \|y - v\|^2 + \|u\|^2.\end{align}$$
Thus $\|y - x\|^2$ is minimized when $y = v = P(x)$. That is,
$$P(x) = \operatorname{argmin}_{y\in V} \|y - x\|^2$$

(2) $\implies$ (1):

$P(x) = \operatorname{argmin}_{y\in V} \|y - x\|^2$. If $x \perp V$, then for all $ 0 \ne y \in V$, 
$$\|y - x\|^2 = \|y\|^2 + \|x\|^2 > \| 0 - x\|^2$$
Therefore $P(x) = 0$. In particular, since $0 \perp V, P(0) = 0$. Conversely, for any $x$ with $P(x) = 0$, any $y \in V$ with $\|y\| = 1$, and any $a \ne 0$, we know that $$\|ay - x\|^2 > \|0 - x\|^2$$
$$a^2 - 2\langle ay, x\rangle + \|x\|^2 > \|x\|^2$$
$$\frac {a^2} 2 > a\langle y, x\rangle.$$
Since this holds for all $a \ne 0$, it must be that $\langle y, x\rangle = 0$. For general nonzero $y \in V$, 
$$\langle y, x\rangle = \|y\|\left\langle \frac y {\|y\|}, x\right\rangle = \|y\|0 = 0.$$ Therefore $\ker P = V^\perp$.

If $y, v \in V$, then $\|y - (x + v)\| = \|(y - v) - x\|$. Hence $y = P(x + v)$ if and only if $y - v = P(x)$. I.e., for $v \in V$, $P(x + v) = P(x) + v$.

Three consequences:

- For $y \in V, P(y) = P(0 + y) = P(0) + y = 0 + y = y$.
- Since for all $x \in H, P(x) \in V$, we have $P(P(x)) = P(x)$. That is, $P^2 = P$.
- For $x \in H, P(x) \in V$, so $P(x - P(x)) = P(x) - P(x) = 0$. Therefore $x - P(x) \in V^\perp$.

Define $x^\perp := x - P(x)$, so $x = x^\perp + P(x)$.

Now for $u \in H$, $$\begin{align}P(x + u) &= P(x^\perp +P(x) + u^\perp + P(u))\\ &= P(x^\perp + u^\perp) + P(x) + P(u)\end{align}$$ since $P(x) + P(u) \in V$. But $x^\perp$ and $u^\perp \in V^\perp$, and since $V^\perp$ is a closed under addition, $x^\perp + u^\perp \in V^\perp$. So $P(x^\perp + u^\perp) = 0$ and $$P(x + u) = P(x) + P(u).$$

Lastly, if $ a\in \Bbb R, a\ne 0, \|y - ax\| = |a|\left\|\frac y a - x\right\|$ Thus $y = P(ax)$ if and only if $\frac y a = P(x)$. Therefore $P(ax) = aP(x)$. Also, $P(0x) = P(0) = 0 = 0x$, so $P$ is linear.

Comment: so what would those conditions be?

Comment: That $P$ is an orthogonal projection. I.e., $\ker P \perp V$

Comment: $P(x) = \operatorname{argmin}_{y\in V}\langle y - x, y - x \rangle^2$ if and only if $P$ is linear, $P^2 = P$, and $\ker P \perp V$.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  Also where can i find a proof of this (to see all the details, using analysis not Linear algebra)

Comment: @CSA - I've added a complete proof. I also realized you need $V$ to be closed for the argmin condition to be defined. So that is one more condition.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for the extremely thorough answer Paul!  Amazing stuff! :)